# OL 3:how displaying geojson

Tags: openlayers-3

I would want to know if there is a known bug with ol.format.geoJSON class in OL 3.5. When I try to create a new source vector from a geoJSON,  it's not displayed on the map. Instead, if I use the same data converted in KML format (ol.format.KML), I get the layer correctly displayed on the map. Can you please help me to fix the problem? Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Comment: You will have to show some code! You can see [a basic example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/r6f3s6r0/).

Comment: Try the drag&drop example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/drag-and-drop.html You can drag&drop your geojson file to the map and see if it loads your data.

Comment: Thank you very much, my initial geojson file was corrupted. It works now very well.